# SwiftUI: popup does not dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, performance, popup, swiftui

In a Swift-UI List (iOS), showing some CoreData Elements, I want to show a popup for each listelement to change an Attribute of the CoreData Element.

In the code below, it is not possible to dismiss the popup.
If I remove the `.id(UUID())` from the List, it works fine.

The `.id(UUID())` is needed in my app, because I change the predicate "on the fly" and that's the only way I know, to avoid that SwiftUI tries to compare all List-elements of the old and the new result.
This performance issue was discussed in [Performance Issue with SwiftUI List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604764/performance-issue-with-swiftui-list)

Any Ideas how to solve this?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @FetchRequest(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: nil) var items: FetchedResults<Item>

  var body: some View {
    VStack
    { Button("Create Testdata"){createTestdata()}
      List(items, id: \.self)
      { item in
        Line(item: item)
      }.id(UUID())
    }
  }
}

struct Line: View {
  @ObservedObject var item : Item
  @State var showSheet = false

  var body: some View {
    Text(item.text!)
    .onLongPressGesture {
      self.showSheet.toggle()// = true
    }
    .popover( isPresented: self.$showSheet,
              arrowEdge: .trailing
            )
    { Pop(showSheet: self.$showSheet, item: self.item )
    }
  }
}

struct Pop: View {
  @Binding var showSheet: Bool
  var item : Item
    //@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           Text("CHANGE TO XXXXXXXXX")
            .onTapGesture
            { self.item.text = "XXXXXXX"
              self.showSheet = false
            }
            Text("CHANGE TO YYYYYYYYY")
            .onTapGesture
            { self.item.text = "YYYYYY"
              self.showSheet = false
            }
            Button("Cancel")
            {
                #if os(OSX)
                NSApp.sendAction(#selector(NSPopover.performClose(_:)), to: nil, from: nil)
                #else
                //self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() // << behaves the same as below
                self.showSheet = false
                #endif
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you ever try init(entity: NSEntityDescription, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor], predicate: NSPredicate?, animation: Animation?) animation parameter?

Comment: great!!works fine. Can you explain, what the problem was and how the animation solves it?